# Prove at least two numbers $(a,b)$ exist such that $a|b$ or $b|a$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

We have this set : $$A=\{1,2,3, \dots , n\}$$

We choose $\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil+1$ numbers from $A$. Can we prove that at least two numbers exist that are divisible ? (In other words, either $a\mid b$ or $b\mid a$.)

Example : If $A = \{1,2,3,\dots ,20\}$ we must choose $11$ numbers to get at least two numbers divisible.

Comment: It is obvious that $1|3$

Comment: My mean is GCD not HCF

Comment: Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) = Highest Common Factor (HCF). Your last statement (in brackets) has slightly different from the rest of the question.

Comment: If $n$ is odd , for example $n=5$ we must choose $3$ numbers.

Comment: Don't you mean $a\mid b$ or $b\mid a$?

Comment: Yes , my mean is $b|a$ .

Comment: This is false if $n = 5$ and we choose $3,4,5$.

Comment: So , you think it is false for odd numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is true, but only if $n$ is even. There are a lot of counterexamples which are clearly mentioned in comments and other answers too that explains why $n$ can not be odd.

HINT: Try pigeonhole principle.

By factoring out as many $2's$ as possible, any number from the given set can be written as $2^k.a$ where  $a$ is odd number and $k\ge0$.

For example $12=2^2\times 3$ and $3$ is odd. $28=2^2\times 7$ and $7$ is odd. $33=2^0\times 33$ and $33$ is odd etc.

Now $a$ can be any odd i.e. $1,3,5...... $ From the given set and there will be $\frac{n}{2}$ of such numbers ($a$). So whenever you select $\frac{n}{2} + 1$th  number there must be two numbers  having the same value of $a$.  For example $l=2^p\times a$ and $m=2^q\times a$.

When $p>q$  then $m|l$ and when $q>p$ then $l|m$.

Comment: Can you explain "By factoring out as many 2's as possible, any number from the given set can be written as $2^k$" ?

Comment: Can you determine $a$ and $k$ in your answer ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still unable to understand your solution .

Comment: Okay , Thank you a lot.

Comment: @S.H.W, now see the answer

Comment: "there will be $\frac{n}{2}$ of such numbers (a)" . What is your mean by this ?

Comment: You write any number in $2^k . a$ form . What is next step ?

Comment: @S.H.W, there are n numbers in the set and n is even so there will be n/2 even numbers and n/2 odd numbers (1,3,5,7,9...)

Comment: the purpose to write the numbers in the form $2^k.a$ was that so that we  can eliminate even numbers and deal only with odd numbers (a)..

Comment: still confused??

Comment: @S.H.W If you are confused please tell me I can give more effort so that you can fully understand..

Comment: I almost understand it and I need time to think about it . Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome then..

Answer (score 2):

No, let $n=3$ such that $A = \{1,2,3\}$. Now we pick $\lfloor \frac{3}{2} \rfloor + 1 = 2$ numbers from $A$, being $2$ and $3$. These are relatively prime hence not divisible.

Comment: Please check it again .

Comment: @S.H.W are you also including pair of (3,1)?

Comment: Yes , (1,3) is valid

Comment: And you are only assuming continues numbers starting from 1?

Comment: Your mean is natural numbers ?

Comment: Yes continues natural number from 1?

Comment: Yes , exactly . natural numbers from 1

Comment: One last question we can choose randomly number from set like this user choose or we if we have 7 numbers then according to your formula its 4 numbers we have to choose. We pick randomly or first four numbers from 1-4?

Comment: We can choose it randomly.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2m+1>1$ choose $x$ for $m+1\leq x\leq 2m-1$ and choose  $m$ and choose $2m+1.$ This gives $m+2$ numbers, no two of which are divisors of each other. For even $n,$ I dk.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is **true** for odd n. We are asked to choose $\frac{n+1}{2}$ numbers from the set (the ceiling function). And so there are $\frac{n-1}{2}$ odd natural numbers not bigger than n, excluding 1 whose case is obvious.